# Slide down page content

Tags: wordpress

How to put the content of the page into a slide down div in Wordpress? For example, I have 3 menu items. Home | Services | Contact.

Instead of redirecting to a single page When "Services" is clicked, it will just stay on the same page but a slide down will appear underneath the "Services" containing the page content.

Help anyone?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this.
At first add a css id attribute to the service section div.
example id: **service**
Then put  **#service** as link's href attribute.
Then let me know the result.

Thanks

Comment: I will try it. that would be a bit difficult I think because the menu is generated by wp_nav_menu in Wordpress so I can't put a #services to the link and put the div#services underneath it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I actually know what you meant. I will just do it with jQuery anyway. Thanks again!
https://codepen.io/leorapirap/pen/QgeYPp